# solidity mapping does not persist

Tags: solidity

I have this solidity code

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.12

contract Starting { 

    struct itemStatus {
        bool created;
    }
    mapping (bytes => itemStatus) public item;
    
    bool[] public boolArray;    

    function start(bytes memory itemId) public returns (bool[] memory) {
        boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
        if (item[itemId].created) {
            boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
            return boolArray;
        } else {
            item[itemId] = itemStatus(true);
            boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
            return boolArray;
        }
    }
}
```

frontend javascript code is

```
  toStart: function () {
    let Instance;
    App.contracts.Starting.deployed().then(function (instance) {
      Instance = instance;
      return Instance.start.call(itemId);
    }).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },
```

The first time I call 'toStart', I would expect [false, true] and the second time I call with the same itemId [false, true, true, true] and third time [false, true, true, true, true, true]. However, the result is always [false, true] regardless of how many times I call 'toStart'. It seems the values do not persist or get stored. Why is it so? How to change the code to get the expected result? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `cal()` function only makes a call and not a transaction (that would change the contract state).

**Solution:** Call the `start()` function directly to generate an Ethereum transaction

```
return Instance.start(itemId); // correct
```

instead of

```
return Instance.start.call(itemId); // incorrect
```

See Truffle docs about [making a call](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#explicitly-making-a-call-instead-of-a-transaction) and [making a transaction](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#making-a-transaction-via-a-contract-function) for more info.